# ftp batch script fails with Cannot find list of remote files

Tags: batch-file, upload, ftp

I have this script but it says there's no file with that name what am I missing here?

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName=192.168.1.0
Set _UserName=luigal
Set _Password=*****
Set _LocalFolder=C:\Users\rs\Desktop\fold_1848E\
Set _RemoteFolder=/pools/A/A0/Backups/lgal
Set _Filename=Readme.txt
Set _ScriptFile=ftp1
:: Create script
 >"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo lcd %_LocalFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo cd %_RemoteFolder%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo binary
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo prompt
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo mget %_Filename%
>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo quit
:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
Del "%_ScriptFile%"
pause
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `ls` command before the `mget` and show us the output. I.e.: `>>"%_ScriptFile%" Echo ls`

Comment: here it is http://postimg.org/image/w63u8m8ph/ @MartinPrikryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see yourself in the [script output you've shared this us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYo7w.png), there are no files at all in the directory you try to download the `Readme.txt` from:

```
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
226 Transfer complete
```

Were there any files, the listing would be shown between `150` and `226` messages.

---

I see you have used [upload](/questions/tagged/upload) tag. Yet you use the [`mget` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-mget). That's for download. Maybe you wanted to use the [`mput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-mput_1), which is for upload (or actually the [`put`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-put), as you do not use wildcards).

---

Though note that your [`lcd` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-lcd) failed, so you are not in the directory you (probably) want to upload the file from.

```
ftp> lcd C:\Users\... (obfuscated) ...
\Users\ ... (obfuscated) ...: File not found
```